# Fetch webpage including jQuery post in Crontab

Tags: php, jquery, python, linux, curl

I want to make a cronjob that simply "visits" a webpage as a normal browser. On this webpage I have a script:

```
<script>
var x = 0;

while(x<10) {

     setTimeout(
     function() {

        if ($(".instashow-gallery-media-image img")[0]){ // If image exists

        var html = $('#instaWrapper').html();
        $('#content').val(html);

        x = 10; // Breaks the loop

        setTimeout(
        function() {
           $('#contentSubmit').submit();
           }, 2000); // Wait 2 seconds, then submit             

        } else {
          // Couldn't find the image, trying again
        }

        }, 1000);

        x++;
     }
 </script>
```

If I do a curl in the terminal, the javascript won't run and the posting will never happen. 
Is there a "curl" that simulates an actual visit like Chrome, Safari etc? Or can I write a Php or Python script that I can add in my crontab?

Thanks!

Comment: Use something like Selenium to mimic human behaviour.

Comment: Seems cool @fedorqui but it seems to open up firefox window in the GUI. I want a terminal/scripting based solution only (if possible)

Comment: you can use headless browser like phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL in PHP like so:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Enter your browser agent string here');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($status == 200) {
    // $output contains URLs data, if needed
}
```

If you set `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` to your desired user agent string, then the request will appear to come from that browser.

I guess it depends on what you want to do with the data, whether you just want to ping the URL, or whether you want to do actually display the website as if it were that browser visiting it.